# Error System.BadImageFormatException, Couldn't not load assembly, using C#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm having difficulty because i can't load my assembly. I can't because when i join them together and after split the assemblies using a `DELIMITER` the image of my files are corrupted. The result is well and i can see perfectly the same assembly, however when i do the split, my file will return me `System.BadImageFormatException`.
Here is the program that i did for joining the files:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Crypter
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //No Arguments -> Exit
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax: crypter.exe <Exe/Dll to get Encrypted> <Password> (Optional: output file name)");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            String file = args[0];
            String pass = args[1];
            String outFile = "Crypted.exe";

            //If Output Name is specified -> Set it
            if (args.Length == 3)
            {
                outFile = args[2];
            }

            //File doesn't exist -> Exit
            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[!] The selected File doesn't exist!");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            //Everything seems fine -> Reading bytes
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Data...");
            byte[] plainBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            //Yep, got bytes -> Encoding
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Encoding Data...");
            byte[] encodedBytes = encodeBytes(plainBytes, pass);

            Console.WriteLine("[*] Save to Output File... ");

            //Leer el stub
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Stub...");
            byte[] Stub = File.ReadAllBytes("Stub.exe");

            //byte separador
            string strseperate = "BLAUMOLAMUCHO";
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strseperate);
            //byte[] toBytes = new byte[30];

            //write bytes
            //var stream
            //Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("skip.skip.exe");
            //Console.WriteLine(stream);
            var s = new MemoryStream();
            s.Write(Stub, 0, Stub.Length);
            s.Write(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);
            s.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
            var b3 = s.ToArray();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(b3);


            //Stream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedBytes);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"out.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
                fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            Console.WriteLine("\n[*] File successfully encoded!");
        }
        private static byte[] encodeBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

And then i open since the first program, stub.. the program is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Resources;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace skip
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// MAIN
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());

            //leemos el byte array
            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            //obtenemos la string
            string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);
            string[] arr=str.Split(new string[] { "BLAUMOLAMUCHO" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string a = arr[0];
            string b = arr[1];

            /*Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.ReadKey();*/


            byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b);
            RunInternal(encodedBytes,"1234");




         }

        private static void RunInternal(byte[] exeName, String pass)
        {
            //Read the raw bytes of the file
            byte[] resourcesBuffer = exeName;

            //Decrypt bytes from payload
            byte[] decryptedBuffer = null;
            decryptedBuffer = decryptBytes(resourcesBuffer, pass);



            //If .NET executable -> Run
            if (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBuffer).Contains("</assembly>")) //Esto devuelve false
            {
                //Load the bytes as an assembly
                Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(decryptedBuffer);

                //Execute the assembly
                object[] parameters = new object[1];                //Don't know why but fixes TargetParameterCountException

                try{
                    exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBuffer));
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt the Loaded Assembly Bytes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="payload"></param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted Bytes</returns>
        private static byte[] decryptBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it's possible because i did in other languages like `autoit`. And my binary add perflectly the delimiter that i can see when i convert to string:

```
MZ? ♥   ♦   ??  ?       @                                   ?   ♫▼?♫ ?  ?!?☺L?!T
his program cannot be run in DOS mode.
$       PE  L☺♥ ?4‼Y        ? ☻☺♂☺♂  ♫       N,       @    @      ☻  ♦       ♦
      ?   ☻      ♥ @?  ►  ►    ►  ►      ►           ?+  S    @   ♣
      `  ♀   ?*  ∟                                                         H
       .text   T♀       ♫   ☻                 `.rsrc    ♣   @   ♠   ►
   @  @.reloc  ♀    `   ☻   ▬              @  B                0,      H   ☻ ♣ ?
!  $      ☺   ☺  ♠                                                ‼0☻ @   ☺  ◄ (
↕
 ▬(‼
 (¶
o§
(▬

▼→(↨
♂(↑
♠o↓
(→
 (←
&*←0♥ ?   ☻  ◄ ☻(∟
‼♣◄♣-♣8?   ☻(▬

¶♂♠♥(♥  ♠♂(↑
o↓
r☺  po↔
▬?☺‼♣◄♣-9 (▲
o▼    ☺
¶       o
& ?¶‼♦ ◄♦(!
 (←
& ?   +↓ (↑
o↓
(→
 (←
& *☺►    P ↕b ¶▼  ☺‼0♣ B   ♥  ◄ ("
♥o#

        -?☻♀+*  BSJB☺ ☺     ♀   v4.0.30319    ♣ l   ?☻  #~  H♥  (♦  #Strings
p  ∟   #US ?  ►   #GUID   ?  ?☺  #Blob       ☻  ☺G§☻        ?%3 ▬  ☺       ☻   ♥
   ♦   #   ☼   ♥   ☺   ☻
 ☺     ♠ 0 ) ♠ ? h ♠ ? ? ♠ ? ? ♠ ? ? ♠ ♠☺? ♠ ▼☺? ♠ 8☺? ♠ S☺? ♠ n☺? ♠ ?☺?☺♠ ?☺?☺♠
 ?☺? ♠ ?☺? ♠ ◄☻?☺? %☻  ♠ T☻4☻♠ t☻4☻♠ ?☻)
 ?☻?☻♠ ?☻? ♠ 0♥&♥♠ B♥) _ N♥  ♠ v♥j♥♠ ?♥) ♠ ?♥) ♠ ?♥) ♠ ?♥? ♠ ?♥? ♠ ♦♦) ♠ #♦)
 ☺     ☺ ☺ ?☺► ‼ ← ♣ ☺ ☺ P     ? 7
 ☺ ?     ? < ♫ ☺ L!    ? H ¶ ♥   ☺ U   ☻ ]   ☺ b   ☻ ] ◄ ? ∟ ↓ ? ∟ ! ? ∟ ) ? ∟ 1
 ? ∟ 9 ? ∟ A ? ∟ I ? ∟ Q ? ∟ Y ? ! a ? ∟ i ? ∟ q ? ∟ y ? & ? ? , ? ? 1 ? ? 1 ? ?
☻
 ? ?☻: ? ♦♥? ? ↓♥D ? 5♥H ? \♥N ? ⌂♥T ? ?♥Y ? ?♥_ ? ?♥d ? ?♥p ? ?♥u ? ?♥z ? ?♥? ?
 ?♥? ? ?♥? ? ♫♦T ? →♦?   ? 5 . ; ☺. ‼ ? . ← ☺☺. # ☺☺. + ☺☺. 3 ? . ♂ ? . C ☺☺. S
☺☺. [ ▼☺. k I☺. s V☺. { _☺. ? h☺i ? ? ♦?  ☺             ←   ♦           ☺
♦           ☺ ?☻         <Module> skip.exe Program skip mscorlib System Object M
ain RunInternal decryptBytes exeName pass bytes System.Runtime.Versioning Target
FrameworkAttribute .ctor System.Reflection AssemblyTitleAttribute AssemblyDescri
ptionAttribute AssemblyConfigurationAttribute AssemblyCompanyAttribute AssemblyP
roductAttribute AssemblyCopyrightAttribute AssemblyTrademarkAttribute AssemblyCu
ltureAttribute System.Runtime.InteropServices ComVisibleAttribute GuidAttribute
AssemblyVersionAttribute AssemblyFileVersionAttribute System.Diagnostics Debugga
bleAttribute DebuggingModes System.Runtime.CompilerServices CompilationRelaxatio
nsAttribute RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute STAThreadAttribute System.Windows.Form
s Application EnableVisualStyles SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault Assembly GetE
xecutingAssembly get_Location System.IO File ReadAllBytes Environment SpecialFol
der GetFolderPath System.Text Encoding get_ASCII GetString Console WriteLine Con
soleKeyInfo ReadKey Exists String Contains Load MethodInfo get_EntryPoint Method
Base Invoke Exception get_Unicode GetBytes Byte  ↨< / a s s e m b l y >     ????
=??J?▲??R???z\V↓4??♥  ☺♣ ☻☺♫♫ ☻↔♣↔♣♫♦ ☺☺♫♦ ☺☺☻♣ ☺☺◄A♦ ☺♥  ☺♦☺   ♦ ☺☺☻♦  ↕U♥  ♫♣
♠↔♣↔♣↕U↔∟↕}☻♣ ☺↔♦↔♣☻G☺ →.NETFramework,Version=v4.0☺ T♫¶FrameworkDisplayName►.NET
 Framework 4    ☺ ♦Stub  ♣☺    ↨☺ ↕Copyright ??  2017  )☺ $0f86beb5-80bf-47f1-89
e1-df778adbda88  ♀☺ 1.0.0.0☺ ☺       ▲☺ ☺ T☻▬WrapNonExceptionThrows☺     ?4‼Y
 ☻   ∟☺  ?*  ?♀  RSDS§2??♦YL?{Q‼????☺   c:\Users\Androide\Desktop\CRYPTER SIN DR
OPEAR\Stub\obj\Debug\skip.pdb

                                                             ,          >,
                    0,                _CorExeMain mscoree.dll     ?%  @





                                  ☻ ►      ?↑   8  ?              ☺ ☺   P  ?
          ☺ ☺   h  ?              ☺     ?                 ☺     ?   ?@  ?☻
    0C  ?☺          ?☻4   V S _ V E R S I O N _ I N F O     ?♦??  ☺   ☺       ☺
    ?       ♦   ☺               D   ☺ V a r F i l e I n f o     $ ♦   T r a n s
l a t i o n       ?♦?☺  ☺ S t r i n g F i l e I n f o   ?☺  ☺ 0 0 0 0 0 4 b 0
4 ♣ ☺ F i l e D e s c r i p t i o n     S t u b      ☺ F i l e V e r s i o n
 1 . 0 . 0 . 0   4       ☺ I n t e r n a l N a m e   s k i p . e x e     H ↕ ☺ L
 e g a l C o p y r i g h t   C o p y r i g h t   ?     2 0 1 7   <       ☺ O r i
 g i n a l F i l e n a m e   s k i p . e x e     , ♣ ☺ P r o d u c t N a m e
 S t u b      ☺ P r o d u c t V e r s i o n   1 . 0 . 0 . 0   8 ☺ A s s e m b l
y   V e r s i o n   1 . 0 . 0 . 0   ???<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" stan
dalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>


                                                                          ♀   P<






                      BLAUMOLAMUCHO|Z? 0 4 5 2 ??4 ? 2 3 4 q 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
94 1 2 3 4 1 2 ? 4 ?▼?♫3?=?►?3L?!`hXs↕pAoSrPm↕cRnZoE Pe‼rAn◄i\ wOg \oVe↔
§ 2 3 4 aE2 ⌂☺7 ??#Y3 4 1 2 ? 6☺:☺☻ 42 3 4 ?'2 3 4 1@2 3 t 1 2 3☻4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3
 4 1?2 3☻4 1 2 0 t?1 " 3►4 1 " 3►4 1 2 # 4 1 2 3 4 Q'2 | 4 1@2 ?♣4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
 4 1`2 ? 4 ↓&2 / 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ; 4 1 2 3 4 9 2 {
 4 1 2 3 4 ▼tWxG 4 ?2 3 42 3☻4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ‼ 4`▼rArP 4 ?♣2 3@4 1♠2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 s 4@▼rWl\c4 = 2 3`4 1☻2 3►4 1 2 3 4 1 2 s 4B1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ?'2 3
4 y 2 1 1 M 2 ?♣4 2 2 2 4♠1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 O @☺3
D(< 2
3r/ 1p→♫3 > &(= 3
↕*‼☻→►3 > ← 2 qS~B0 3 3 4 = 2 E4→0▼3☻3☻94 1 7 _ 4 ?☺2 ►~4 §☻2 w☻4 ↕SFrZnSs1 2 [♦
4 Q 2 ►Ug ?♦2 # 4 ↕GgIw 4 ?♦2 ? 4 ↕B^oQ 4 1 2 1 4☺v§2 : 4 1?333▬4 0 2 # 4 3 2 1
4 0 2 # 4 = 2 2 4 0 2 3 Q☺0 2 3 2 ? ?☺5 s☺?☺4 ↑ ?☺> -☻3 2 b ?☺5 ? ?☺4 ? ?☺7 ∟☺?☺
 ?☺2 ? C☺5 ☻?☺4   ?☺7 ?☺?☺4 1 3 3 4 0 3 3 $ ?☺?☺
 5 0 b 3 4 ? ?☺↔ 5 A 2 3 ?↑?☺4 1 4 0 ∟☻: ?☺0 # ?☺2 ( ?☺9 ↔ ?☺" ☻ ?☺! ♂ ?☺$ p ?☺#
 } ?☺" b ?☺! k ?☺$ P ?☺& ] ?☺" J / + K ▬ . ☻, E ?☺4 ↔ ? ♣ ∟      ▼ ) o → ↕ W ↔ ▼
 C ∟   F ▼       A → r W ↔ ⌂ I ∟ ` F ▼ i A → R ? 7?4 0 2 ?↑¶W1 2 3 ' 1 6 3 4 1 2
 3 ◄ ; 2 3 4 1<⌂oWuXe☼ _sPoFlXb2C\nGo]e2WAi@e}i\e3WFiEe2DVbAgVaPlVA@tCiPuGe4C^md
i@iVlTAFtAiVuEe2A@sQmSlKTZtXeptFrZbAtT ss@eYb]yfrRdQmPrYAGtFiSuFe3TUrVeFFAaYeFo@
krt@rXbGtV usBe_b_ywo_f[gFrUtXo\AGtFiSuFe3AGsTmPlJDQsRr[pGi[nptFrZbAtT qo^p]lPt[
o]RQlPxStZoZsptFrZbAtT ss@eYb]ybr\dAcEAFtAiVuEe2A@sQmSlKC\pMrXgZtrt@rXbGtV usBe_
b_ywo\pSnJA@tCiPuGe4RDnFi^ewo\pStZb]lXtKAGtFiSuFe3C[nBo^e↔eLe1SKsGeY.cu\tZmQ.ge@
sZoZi_g2C\nGo] br\gFa\ ay@tQm1MSi] gyBtWm↔RQf]eQtZoZ ro\s\lQKTy{nUo4.Rt]r3SMsEe_
.wiUg_oAtZcG byAtVm→RDnFi^e→I_tWr\pgeCv[cVs4SHsFe^.fu_t[mV.wo\p[lVrgeCv[cVs4DTbG
gTiZg|oVe@ UrVs2OQjQcE `eRd⌂eH 2 3↓| T ^ _ [ ◄ e \ F ] V ↕ 4Aa @ V G B ↕ R Z H ↕
 X Q H ↕ G [ ◄ Q \ Z E [ ] A T ↕ ↔ ¶ ▼ ↕ ↔ ¶ 1 2 ◄?Zi?n?O?}??H?A?3♦¶☺1 3☺1 0☺#◄7
 5☺?♦↕☺2☻0 0☺<♣3☺%A?zoV-4??7 2☺)♫9☺3 4 1▲3 2 `☻'W@aCN[ntxQeCt]o_TZr\wG☺9☺22 4 1♀
3 4C[nBo^e3 1☺1 2  ☺4♫roByAiShE  0☻74 v☺2→↔NqTwrSmVw[rZ,deAs]o_=D4↔05 e♫&FAaYeFo
@kwiGp]aKNRmQ►▼NwT‼FFa\eEoAk¶41 2 ??%Y1 2 1 4 -☺2 w&4 2 aSpS←#??l??G?:?→???40 2
p:hUBe@soAZdCo[dV\poRu_e]tG\bhSrCDQvTl]p‼PFo[eQt@\wo_s]lV\wo_s]lV\[b[\veQuS\ro\s
\lQ.AdP 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ?'2 3 4 1 2 ?'4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ?'2 3 4 1 2 3 kC^rwx
VMUi_ _sPoFeT.Vl_ 4 1 ?%3 t 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 6 ! 2 ‼ 4?) 2 c 4?1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 0 2 ♂ 4?1 2
3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 ? 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 0 2 [ 4?1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 ?♥4 ?@2 ♣♥4 1 2
3 4 ♥♠ 3 b b m e q c a z { ⌂ m z z w } 3 4 ?♦??3 5 1 3 ‼W?↑1 3 ‼W?↑♫ 2 3 4 5 2 2
 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 w 4 0 d R F w [ _ Q x \ U [ 1 2 ↨ 0 1 f A U _ A _ U E [ \ Z 1 2 3
 ?♦?☻2 2 g E @ Z Z V t Z X T { ] R ^ 2 A☻4 0 ☻ ♥ ♦ ☺ ☻  V ☺ 2 ) 5 0 q \ Y \ W ]
@ B 2 3 4 ‼ 3 2 w ^ _ C U _ K } U \ W 3 4 1 2 ♂ < 0 t Z X T v V G R @ Z D E [ \
 ; 0 t Z X T d V F B [ \ Z 1 2 ☻ → ☺ ∟ ♣  ☻
 ↔ ♠ ♥ ☺ ♥   1 2 ♂ 8 0 { ] @ T @ ] U ] | R Y T 2 p [ _ A \ X T ∟ V L T 2 q ; 0 ~
 V S P ^ p [ A K A ] V Z G 4 r ] C M C [ T \ E ↕ ☺ ♦   ♣ 3 4 ← 3 2 x T U R X e @
 R P T _ R F Z A 3 4 1 2 s 8 0 } A ] V [ ] U ] t Z X T \ R Y T 2 p [ _ A \ X T ∟
 V L T 2 ♥ < 0 b A [ U G P @ ⌂ S ^ Q 1 2 p [ _ A \ X T 2 q ; 0 b A [ U G P @ g W
 A G X ] ] 4   ∟ ♥ →  ☺   ♀ ▼   ☺  ☺ ♠ 3 4 w = 2 u B A V Y S ^ J ¶ g W A G X ] ]
 4   ∟ ♥ →  ☺   ♀ ▼   ☺  ☺ ♠ 3 4 ?C2 ?☺4 1 2 3 4 ???<♀xYl◄vWr@i[n♀"♥.♥"¶e_c]dZnS
=‼UfF▲8▬ BtSnWaXo_e☼"JeG"♫>?
>
aBsWmQlM Im^n@=▬uCsPhQmPs▼mZcFoBoTt▲c[m♂aAm↔v♣"◄mSnZfQsEVWr@i[n♀"♥.♥"
8 ‼ ¶ ◄<@eBuQsEeVPAiBi]eUe@ Lm]nA=◄uFn♂sQhVmUs∟m[cAoGoWt▼c\m♫aBm∟v "
; ↕ ‼ ¶ ◄<@eBuQsEeVEKeWuEi]n⌂eBe] ^eEeX=‼aAI]v[kTr► FiucReAs♫"Ra]sW"∟>9
◄ ↕ ‼/CeCuVs@eUP@iEiXeVeA>>
><▲aAsVmVlH>2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ?
4 ?72 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Error return's me:

[image]

If you search in the assembly you will see perflectly the `DELIMITER`, `BLAUMOLAMUCHO`. I tried including the length's but i must to use streamreader because it's not data.
How i can load two assemblies without using like resource in c#(it's only for educational purposes and learning.)

Comment: Just to narrow down where the problem is: In your decode function, write the decoded bytes to file and verify that input and output files are exactly the same. If they are, try to load the assembly from the output file.

Comment: When you read the file and convert it to string you are corrupting all the binary data, all the non-representable chars will be lost, and at the moment the system finds a '\0' will consider the string finished, that's why it does not remove the "BLAUMOLAMUCHO" string. You must use some other method to find the separator, but in your case I would have a "footer", at the end of the file add an struct with offsets to know where the files start and how long they are.